# How can I interpret the residualplots

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, linear

I have this plot and need some interpretation. The response variable of my data is Salary and the predictors are, Education, experience, age, kids, GPA, and Assets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The residuals appear to be evenly distributed around the zero-line (residual = 0) so the linearity assumption for inference holds, and there is no odd shape to the residuals (fanning or wavy for example) so our equal variance assumption for inference holds.